# Cant connect to MySQL Server after upgrade to server 8.0.13

Tags: mysql

I upgraded to MySQL 8.0.13 from version 8.0.11.
After running the installer I get to this screen/window[Please See link for pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZWIe.png)

I know what the password is and have entered it many times.

My research has lead me to beleive the MySQL80 service is not running. I have tried to restart the service but only get the following message:

"mysql error 2003 (hy000) cant connect to MYSQl server on localhost (10061)" I have followed other threads with this error but they do not relate to my problem.

I have backed up my connection in a zip file on workbench.

I have tried running mysqld --intialize and --console

Here is the error log I am getting from the file 'DESKTOP-DSNA0DJ.err'

2018-11-06T18:21:20.600566Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.11) starting as process 5724
2018-11-06T18:21:26.159234Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2018-11-06T18:21:26.273780Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.11'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2018-11-07T14:30:30.620654Z 0 [System] [MY-013105] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown.
2018-11-07T14:30:32.638014Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 23  user: 'root'.
2018-11-07T14:30:33.697523Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.11)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2018-11-07T14:40:37.146177Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000081] [Server] option 'read_buffer_size': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 8192.
2018-11-07T14:40:37.150491Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000081] [Server] option 'read_rnd_buffer_size': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1.
2018-11-07T14:40:37.153567Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2018-11-07T14:40:37.192517Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 5840
2018-11-07T14:40:45.019662Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013178] [Server] Execution of server-side SQL statement 'INSERT INTO tables SELECT *, 0 FROM mysql.tables' failed with error code = 1292, error message = 'Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'created' at row 340'.
2018-11-07T14:40:45.092781Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2018-11-07T14:40:45.093917Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-11-07T14:40:46.699916Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2018-11-07T14:54:19.194872Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000081] [Server] option 'read_buffer_size': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 8192.
2018-11-07T14:54:19.194937Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000081] [Server] option 'read_rnd_buffer_size': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1.
2018-11-07T14:54:19.195040Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2018-11-07T14:54:19.199472Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 12120
2018-11-07T14:54:22.718620Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013178] [Server] Execution of server-side SQL statement 'INSERT INTO tables SELECT *, 0 FROM mysql.tables' failed with error code = 1292, error message = 'Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'created' at row 340'.
2018-11-07T14:54:22.767258Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2018-11-07T14:54:22.768805Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-11-07T14:54:24.128744Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)

This is the section where it converts from calling mysqld 8.0.11 to calling version 8.0.13

As you can see it says that

```
"Data Dictionary initialization failed."
```

I have tried creating data directory in c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 8.0\ and added NETWORK SERVICE as a user. But no success. I have a copy of my.ini file that looks like it has not been altered or edited in the upgrade process.

My data base data file is located in the 'program data' folder and not the 'program file' folder. Here is a copy of my.ini file. Please excuse the bad formatting as I am not familiar with stackoverflow. I am new to MySQL and do not have much experience with administrative tasks such as these.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to attach a copy of my.ini file

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, this is pure admin stuff, therefore it is off topic here on SO. You may get more help at the DBA sister site of SO.

Comment: Ok. Have reposted to DBA site https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222061/mysql-server-wont-start-after-upgrade-to-mysql-8-0-13

Comment: The pls delete it from here.